# How to find where NSPrintOperation created the saved PDF (NSPrintSaveJob)

Tags: macos, printing, nsprintoperation, nsprintinfo

I'm using NSPrintOperation to optionally print or save as PDF.  It works great, however, when using Save as PDF (NSPrintSaveJob), NSPrintOperation will put up a standard File Save dialog, and the user can CHANGE the proposed name.

I haven't been able to locate (but see NOTE at end) any returned value that shows the URL of the ultimate final location the user selected for the Save as PDF operation.  For example, I looked in the NSPrintInfo dictionary to see if a key-value pair might have been added by NSPrintOperation, but none was:

[image: Screenshot of NSPrintInfo* record]

Is discovering that URL even possible?

Here's how I initialize the process (which is printing from a temporary .pdf I generated):

```
PDFDocument *pdfDocumentToPrint = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL:(__bridge NSURL*)cfURL];
NSPrintOperation *op = [pdfDocumentToPrint printOperationForPrintInfo:(__bridge NSPrintInfo*)printInfo scalingMode:kPDFPrintPageScaleNone autoRotate:NO];

BOOL doPrintPreview = (((__bridge NSPrintInfo*)printInfo).jobDisposition == NSPrintPreviewJob) ? YES : NO;
BOOL doExportAsPDF = (((__bridge NSPrintInfo*)printInfo).jobDisposition == NSPrintSaveJob) ? YES : NO;

op.showsPrintPanel = !(doPrintPreview || doExportAsPDF);

[op runOperation];

CFRelease(cfURL);
```

**NOTE:** NSPDFInfo* DOES have a URL field that contains the final, user-specified file path, but it's unclear how to obtain an NSPDFInfo after a print operation.

Comment: In my test app, the URL is in the printInfo dictionary with key `NSPrintJobSavingURL`. When did you check? How do you print and save?

Comment: @Willeke - I added a screen shot of the NSPrintInfo* record, after the save panel asks for the updated filename.  I do NOT have NSPrintJobSavingURL.  I've also added some code indicating HOW I'm invoking the NSPrintOperation.

Comment: Which `NSPrintInfo` do you check, `op.printInfo.dictionary`?

Comment: @Willeke -- great idea, but the op.printInfo.dictionary is the same as that NSPrintInfo record I examined... HOWEVER -- there is a field, op.pdfPanel.panel.finalURL, that DOES have it.  But there's no public access method.  ALSO -- NSPDFInfo* contains that field, but it's unclear how to obtain that after a print operation.